Overleaf document compilation timeout for very short document when loading fonts
This was working alright for a while but it suddenly refused to compile. I'm not sure what I should be doing here, as I'm new to using LaTe
X. Here is a minimal working example (I'm using LuaLaTex with Overleaf):
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{bengali}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{japanese}

\babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans}
\babelfont[bengali]{sf}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Noto Sans Bengali}
\babelfont[japanese]{sf}{Noto Sans CJK JP}

\title{yzyzyzy}
%\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author{yzyzyz}
\institute[yzyz]
{ 
    yzyzy
    \vskip 3pt
}
\date{\today} 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

\end{document}


Might be a good idea to cite the errors you get

hello, @daleif , there are no errors as such, the document merely fails to compile, I keep running into the compilation timeout limit - I'm not sure what is going wrong especially since it is a pretty small document

Might be better to change the title to something about overleaf timeout for a simple doc. Though I had expected to the we use of fontspec, but that might be hidden in the babel macros. Not at pc so cannot test

There is nothing wrong in the code. Generating the data for the Japanese font takes some time (in the first run), and Overleaf stops after a few seconds. Maybe the Harfbuzz renderer is faster: \babelfont[japanese]{sf}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Noto Sans CJK JP}.

@DavidCarlisle , my real example is a presentation (which didn't compile), but the minimal working example failed to compile as well, so I am guessing the size isn't a factor here. Are there any web-based alternatives for Overleaf (unfortunately running it locally isn't an option for me at the moment) ?

@JavierBezos, thanks for the insight, I commented out the lines for Bengali and Japanese and left it as \usepackage[english]{babel} and \babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans}  - however, it still failed to compile

@39_watermargin yes I reproduced, however as Javier says it is timing out loading the fonts so the size of document does not matter, it did not even reach begin document. However if you hit recomplie then it will manage to cache more fonts,  your document produces this output if you hit recompile 4 times, After that it should be OK for the rest of the session.

Your code worked fine under LuaLaTeX and a MacTeX2024 distribution after I replaced {Noto Sans Bengali} and {Noto Sans CJK JP} with {Noto Sans Bengali Regular} and {Noto Sans JP Regular}. (The fonts has nine and six "weights", respectively.) Maybe it's important to indicate which weight (say, "Regular") should be the basic weight.

It is timing out caching the font data so the size of document does not matter, it did not even reach begin document. However if you hit recompile then it will manage to cache more fonts.
Your document produces this output

if you hit Recompile 4 times.
After that it should be OK for future runs. The time is taken caching the font data not in actually typesetting with the fonts.
At the time of writing this is directly viewable on overleaf at this link
https://www.overleaf.com/read/yznbhpwwfqfb#4ad7b0
Note that the error is not a TeX error, just a commercial restriction on the free use of this server. So an alternative if you make heavy use of large fonts that take time to set up is to install TeX locally, TeX itself has no time limits on a run.
